# Search for an position of a string

Tags: vb.net, string, textbox

I'm working with VB 2010 and I have a little question. Well I need a special search function for my RichTextBox.

I've a very long string in my RichTextBox1. I've searched for an specific value there:

```
 Dim firstposition As String = CStr(CDbl(TextBox6.Text) * 8 - 7)
    Dim valueofadress = Mid(RichTextBox3.Text, CInt(firstposition), 8)
    TextBox5.Text = valueofadress

    Dim regi1 = Mid(RichTextBox3.Text, 1, CInt(CDbl(TextBox6.Text) * 8))
    Dim t = Split(regi1, tempcode)
    Dim result = UBound(t)

    TextBox4.Text = result.ToString
    TextBox7.Text = regi1.ToString
```

Well this is not the problem. I've an second RichTextBox with a **similar** string. Now I want to search for a string which exists more than 10000 times in this rtb. I want to find out the position of that string. I also have an counter which gives me the number of the string in which position I'm searching for.

This is my counter:

```
Dim regi1 = Mid(RichTextBox3.Text, 1, CInt(CDbl(TextBox6.Text) * 8))
    Dim t = Split(regi1, tempcode)
    Dim result = UBound(t)

    TextBox4.Text = result.ToString
```

Example:

If the counter = 4 and I want to search the string "Hello world" which exists 10 times, then I want the position of the 4th "Hello world" in the RichTextBox. Well, I've tried InStr and IndexOf but without right results...

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the overloads of [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33.aspx), which allows you to specify a starting position for the search:

```
Dim lastFindIndex As Integer = 0
Dim stringToFind As String = "Find me!"
Dim currentNumberOfMatches = 0
Dim matchToStopAt As Integer = 4

While lastFindIndex > -1

    currentNumberOfMatches += 1

    If matchToStopAt = currentNumberOfMatches Then

        Exit While

    End If

    lastFindIndex = MyTextBox.Text.IndexOf(stringToFind, lastFindIndex)

End While
```

When the loop exits, you know where the string was found (`lastFindIndex`) which you can then feed into your other logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but I'm thinking you'd be better off using regular expressions to do this.

Something along the lines of:

```
    Dim pattern As String = TextBox6.Text
    Dim m As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(RichTextBox3.Text, pattern)
```

Now you can loop through your matchcollection - The location of each match can be found via `m([]).Index`. So, for example, you want to find the 4th occurrence of your match, you can use `m(3).index`.

Hope this helps.

PS:

1. Remember to use `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` at the top of your code.
2. This assumes there aren't any special characters (which may need to be escaped in your pattern) in your TextBox6.Text

Answer (score 0):

I also suggest using regular expressions here. I'd go with \b word boundaries and simple function:

```
Public Function SearchForGivenString(text As String, pattern As String, Optional position As Integer = 1) As Match
    Dim found As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(text, "\b" & pattern & "\b")
    Dim returnMe As Match

    If found.Count = 0 Then
        Return returnMe
    ElseIf position > found.Count Then
        Return found(found.Count - 1)
    Else
        Return found(position - 1)
    End If
End Function
```

Then you can use it with something like this:

```
    Dim testString As String = "Something really long as a text string. Something really long as a text string. Something really long as a text string. Something really long as a text string. Something really long as a text string. Something really long as a text string. Something really long as a text string."
    Dim returnMatch As Match = SearchForGivenString(testString, "really", 7)
    If Not IsNothing(returnMatch) Then
        Console.WriteLine(returnMatch.Value & " " & returnMatch.Index)
    End If
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Of course you can send in Textbox4.Text and similar.... and have different output. Point is in reading Index of the return Match.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! But unfortunately this code doesn't return anything...

Comment: Of course it does. If you want 4th "Hello world" from TextBox3, then do it like this: Dim myResult as Match = SearchForGivenString(TextBox3.Text, "Hello world", 4). Position of this string in TextBox 3 is then: myResult.Index